# Is this a bug or my mistake?

Tags: matrix, code-review, graphs-and-networks

This:

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]
AdjacencyMatrix[%] // MatrixForm
```

generates:

[image]

But, this

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5}]
AdjacencyMatrix[%] // MatrixForm
```

generates:

[image]

Obviously, the latter one is not correct. Why?

Comment: Those numbers are not indices. Their indices correspond to the order they appear so effectively you have `{1 -> 2, 3->4, 5->6}`.

Comment: @Kuba: Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuba: Although I understand what you say, it is very difficult to digest the logic behind it. Unless one has insider information about the necessity of ordering the vertices (experts like you and @kglr), one would take the example from the documentation at its face value because edges in a graph are supposed to be representing their positions in `AdjacencyMatrix`. That is what I was assuming until today. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Kuba: Maybe `SparseArray` offers the solution to my argument.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, in graph theory you can use any symbol to label the vertexes e.g. `Graph@{"alice" -> "bob"}`, that is why the `AdjacencyMatrix` has to do with the  order and not the labels.

Comment: @Fortsaint: I understand the logic now.Somehow, I was not thinking of symbols as vertices. Now it makes sense to reorder the vertices with numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the first argument of `Graph` to provide the vertex list to have the indices of `AdjacencyMatrix` to match the vertex indices:

```
g1 = Graph[Range[6], {1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5}];
am1 = AdjacencyMatrix[g1];
am1 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, reorder the rows and columns to match the ordering of vertex list:

```
g2 = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5}];
AdjacencyMatrix[g2][[#, #]] &[Ordering@VertexList[g2]] == am1
```

> True

Comment: But in the first example taken from MMA documentation, `Range[4]` does not exist. I just replicated the same example with a different matrix.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, since `VertexList[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  4 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]` is `{1,2,3,4}` in that example there is no need to use `Range[4]` in the first argument or to reorder the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix.